# QT- Menu's Exit option

Tags: c++, qt

I'm finally about to finish my school project and thought it'd be nice to have an exit option in my drop-down menu, however, no matter what I try I can't make it work. If you could have a look at it in your spare time, I'd really appreciate it (or any suggestions you might have)

```
void MainWindow::on_actionExit_triggered()
{
    connect(this,SIGNAL(triggered()),MainWindow,SLOT(close()));
}
```

Every time I try to debug it, it gives the following error message:

> error: expected primary-expression before ',' token

Comment: EDIT: i already tried connecting it manually in SIGNAL/SLOT connection, but it just won't let me...

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this - when is your `on_actionExit_triggered` function called? Also, if `this` refers to `MainWindow`, does it have a `triggered` signal?

Comment: Huh, appearently it should have a `triggered()` signal, but isn't it done the same way as a normal exit button's case? I mean, I right click on the Exit Menu-> Go to Slot-> triggered() and then just simply  tell him (in a way similar to the above mentioned one) when i click on it(or trigger it) just call for the `MainWindow`'s `close()` slot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You need to pass object pointer to `connect` function, not class name. You should replace `MainWindow` to `this`. It will fix the compilation error.
2. It would be wiser to put `connect` statement in the class constructor. You need to do the `connect` at initialization if you want it to work any time the user presses the menu item.
3. `on_actionExit_triggered` has special name form. Once you create a slot with such a name, Qt will automatically connect it to the `triggered` slot of the `actionExit` action (see [Automatic Connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections) for more information.). So there is no need for `connect` statement at all.
4. The `on_actionExit_triggered` slot will be called when the user presses the menu item. Of course you need to put some implementation in it. For example:

   ```
   void MainWindow::on_actionExit_triggered() {
       QApplication::quit();
   }
   ```

Comment: *special name form* huh? I never knew about that!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdesigner/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections

Comment: This was very helpful. +1  I noticed in the docs it says to also use [`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) (presumably in the `QMainWindow`'s constructor), but I'm not sure if it is necessary.